# Improve IEnumerable<byte> parsing performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I read a file and parse its bytes 5 at a time. The first byte is the header and the last 4 bytes represent the data. (The first package is always a "Velocidad", so don't worry about UltimoRD being null.) The file is about 400 KB.

The performance is awfully slow. I've tried using array, list, and IEnumerable, but I always get the same, sluggish results. How can I improve the runtime?

```
public void Analizar(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
{
    var listado = new List<AnalisisResumenDiarioGenerico>();
    while (bytes.Any())
    {
        var take = bytes.Take(5);
        listado.Add(ObtenerPaquete(take));
        bytes = bytes.Skip(5);
    }
    //InsertInDB(listado);
}

private AnalisisResumenDiarioGenerico ObtenerPaquete(IEnumerable<byte> take)
{
    var tipo = take.First();
    AnalisisResumenDiarioGenerico retorno;
    switch (tipo)
    {
        case 241:
            retorno = new Velocidad(new TimeSpan(take.ToArray()[1], take.ToArray()[2], take.ToArray()[3]), take.ToArray()[4]);
            break;
        case 242:
            retorno = new Chofer(UltimoRD.fecha, BitConverter.ToInt32(take.ToArray(),1));
            break;
        case 243:
            retorno = new Odometro(UltimoRD.fecha, BitConverter.ToInt32(take.ToArray(), 1));
            break;
        default: //should never get here
            throw new FormatException();
    }
    UltimoRD = retorno;
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: What is slow? `Analizar` or `ObtenerPaquete`?

Comment: You have several calls to `ToArray()` in sequence when extracting the values. These calls are not free. You should materialize only one array, then work with it.

Comment: The whole process is slow, so Analizar as a whole is slow. No idea whichi is the most cpu-consuming line however.

Comment: do you need *distict* `Chofer` instance for every single `242` byte ? Say, if you have 3 bytes and all of them `242`, do you *really* need 3 `Chofer` instances ?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i'll make that change. thanks

Comment: use a BinaryReader on the FileStream. As pointed out, `take.ToArray()[2]` will take **all** of the bytes in the IEnumerable, make a new array and then read the second byte

Comment: @Tigran yes because those are events which happen secuentially. Chofer means driver and represents a driver loging in the truck

Comment: Is it slow in a linear fashion, or does it get worse with larger files (ie does time for 400K = 10 * 40K)?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `Analizar` as well?  i.e. how are you opening this file and getting the `IEnumerable<byte>`?

Comment: @CharlesMager I'm just unit testing that method, so The call hierarchy is Analizar(File.ReadAllBytes(path)).

Comment: BinaryReader made the whole process last less than 5 seconds. Thanks James and Alex K!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this instead:

```
public void Analizar(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
{
  var listado = new List<AnalisisResumenDiarioGenerico>();
  using (var e = bytes.GetEnumerator())
  {
    var arr = new byte[5];
    var posModFive = 0;
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
      arr[posModFive] = e.Current;
      posModFive++;
      if (posModFive == 5)
      {
        listado.Add(ObtenerPaquete(arr));
        posModFive = 0;
      }
    }
    if (posModFive != 0) { /* Hey, 5 did not divide the total length! */ }
  }
  //InsertInDB(listado);
}
```

The problem with your own code is that it essentially did this:

```
  bytes.Any();
  bytes.Take(5).First();
  bytes.Take(5).ToArray();

  bytes.Skip(5).Any();
  bytes.Skip(5).Take(5).First();
  bytes.Skip(5).Take(5).ToArray();

  bytes.Skip(5).Skip(5).Any();
  bytes.Skip(5).Skip(5).Take(5).First();
  bytes.Skip(5).Skip(5).Take(5).ToArray();

  bytes.Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Any();
  bytes.Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Take(5).First();
  bytes.Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Take(5).ToArray();

  ...
```

So the same `IEnumerable<>` was being iterated from the beginning really many times. Although `Take` and `Skip` are "lazy", `Any`, `First` and `ToArray` have to actually "pull" out something. And it is pulled through an ever increasing number of `Skip` handlers (`Take` is `` System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.Byte] `` in my version of the Framework; `Take` is probably `yield return` in a loop).

Charles Mager's mention of [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm) in a comment to GazTheDestroyer's answer is highly relevant.

Comment: why Isn't this line bytes = bytes.Skip(5) preventing this to happen? I thought bytes was being replaced with the new list without the first 5 elements, and then I take 5 of the new list, not 5 + 5 of the original list.

Comment: @Vallo because bytes isn't a list. It's an IEnumerable<byte> which is lazily evaluated. `bytes = bytes.Skip(5)`. bytes = bytes.Skip(5).ToList() would both make it a list and force greedy evaluation. but it wouldn't help your performance

Comment: @Vallo Sorry, my "expansion" or "unrolling" of your code was incorrect. I wrote `Take(5).Take(5).Take(5)` but should have written `Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5)`. I tried to fix that. Note that each occurrences of `Any`, `First`, and `ToArray` propagates through the one `Take` and the many `Skip` and forces a new enumerator (`GetEnumerator()`) to be acquired from the original `IEnumerable<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your culprit is probably:

```
bytes = bytes.Skip(5);
```

You are re-allocating a creating a new list every time through the loop.

Just keep the original list and iterate through to the end.

Comment: `Skip` is lazy. No allocation whatsoever.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel After a while, he will be going through `bytes.Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5).Skip(5)`. All those `Skip` in a chain will cost something.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're crazy man. Yes, i agree he will be walking through the collection. But I said, "No allocation whatsoever." and that still holds true. Granted, performance will suck(I realize).

Comment: It's [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm)!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use BynaryReader.

```
public void Analizar(byte[] bytes)
{
    BinaryReader bin = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));
    var listado = new List<AnalisisResumenDiarioGenerico>();
    while (true)
        {
            var take = bin.ReadBytes(5);
            if (take.Count() == 0) break;
            listado.Add(ObtenerPaquete(take));
        }
    Insertar(listado);
}

private AnalisisResumenDiarioGenerico ObtenerPaquete(IEnumerable<byte> take)
    {
        var tipo = take.First();
        var data = take.ToArray();
        AnalisisResumenDiarioGenerico retorno;
        switch (tipo)
        {
            case 241:
                retorno = new Velocidad(new TimeSpan(data[1], data[2], data[3]),data[4]);
                break;
            case 242:
                retorno = new Chofer(UltimoRD.fecha, BitConverter.ToInt32(data,1));
                break;
            case 243:
                retorno = new Odometro(UltimoRD.fecha, BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 1));
                break;
            default: //nunca debería llegar acá
                throw new FormatException();
        }
        UltimoRD = retorno;
        return retorno;
    }
```

This takes ~ 5 seconds to complete.

Comment: For further improvements pass the BinaryReader into `ObtenerPaquete` and use it in there to!

Comment: Why not just do take.ToArray() once? Creating 4 arrays and calling first is not great.

Comment: @JamesBarrass Why? In ObtenerPaquete I only need the 5 bytes, not the whole file.

Comment: @Vallo, The BinaryReader is just a reader for the stream, the stream keeps a note of where you are up to, not the whole source of the stream. And it has convenient methods to convert the next few bytes into most basic types. Instead of creating a new array, skipping a byte which you've already read and converter the result to and Int32 you just call `bin.ReadInt32()` It's already in the correct place in the stream, waiting to read the bit you want next.